# Storing output of a function (with multiple outputs) in matrix

Tags: r

I have a dataset, which is broken into 20 groups. The matrices storing the data for each group (2 columns of data), are stored in a list, so that I can perform functions on each set within a loop. I would like to store the output of any function that I might run in another matrix.

For example, if I run a fitdistr() on all 20 groups, I would like the output of the function stored in a matrix, so that I can call distribution[1] to call the results from group 1. I have tried the following:

```
distribution<-ls()

for(i in (1:20))
  { distribution[[i]]<-fitdistr(as.numeric(data[[i]]$Column2,"normal") }
```

This sucessfully stores the outputs, and I can call:

```
distribution[1]
```

The issue is that the fitdistr() results in 2 columns of data - a mean and a standard deviation. I checked that I cannot call the mean for a given point:

```
names(distribtuion)
"NULL"
```

So I obviously cannot call get the means, say by:

```
distribution[1]$mean
```

I will be looking for trends in the means and standard deviations (and other parameters for other distributions), so I would like to have the results of fitdistr() stored in a matrix somehow if at all possible. Even if I could somehow call only say, the mean, when running the function, then I can just create an empty vector and populated it in a loop, then repeat for the standard deviation.

I have considered creating an empty matrix large enough to store the data (so it would be 20 rows, 1 for each group, and 2 columns, 1 for each calculated value). I'm still not sure how I would dictate that I want the calculated mean stored in column 1 and the calculated standard deviation stored in column 2. Again, it is an issue of asking the function for only one of its multiple outputs at a time.

I've also looked into one of the apply functions, but these do not seem to be appropriate for what I am doing.

Comment: Try doing `distribution[[1]]$mean` (note the two brackets). Also shouldn't it be `estimate`, not `mean`?

Comment: `ls()` is a function that lists the objects in a given enviroment. It returns a character vector.

Comment: ah, yes. I did mean list()

Answer (score 0):

ls() is a function that lists the objects in a given environment. It returns a character vector.

You (probably) mean to have `list()`.

But then you would be growing your list within a loop. Which is the second circle of R hell.

Instead use `lapply` with the appropriate function (hard to tell where you want the `as.numeric` to go, but it is not correct in your example).

something like..

```
distribution <- lapply(data, function(x) fitdistr(as.numeric(x[['Column2']]),"normal"))
```

Comment: The as.numeric is there because I have a large dataset, which has been binned. Each bin retained the headers in the original data, so when I was trying to run the fitdistr() function on the data, I was getting an error.

I'm trying out the line of code you suggested. I'm getting some errors, but I'll keep looking at it and see if I can get it working. I think one issue I may encounter, based on this error:

    Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  attempt to select less than one element

is the fact that some of my bins have zero data points in it.

Comment: @user2154249 -- without a reproducible example I can't help much more.